# C# - How to populate combobox in datagridview only in certain column?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a requirement to populate data in gridview as below.

[image]

I have a table which stores all of this value. For each "Destination Column" and "Type" will be assigned value based on "Source Column". But I have a problem in setting the default value for "Destination Column" and "Type".
Can someone give me an idea. As I have been stuck with this for whole day. Any help is highly appreciated.

Below is the code.

```
string sqlMatchedData = "SELECT convert(integer, 100 * SIMILARITY) AS SIMILARITY, SOURCE_NAME " + 
                        "FROM TB_LOOKUP_COLUMN WHERE SOURCE_NAME IN (" + allColumnName + ")";
ds = databaseManager.GetData(sqlMatchedData);
//dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
//dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false;
//dataGridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;

dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr;
dt.Columns.Add("Similarity (%)");
dt.Columns.Add("Source Column");
//dt.Columns.Add("C");
//dt.Columns.Add("D");

foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    string v = row[0].ToString();
    string v1 = row[1].ToString();
    //string v2 = row[2].ToString();
    //string v3 = row[3].ToString();

    dr[0] = v;
    dr[1] = v1;
    //dr[2] = v2;
    //dr[3] = v3;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

//LookupColumn
string sqlLookupColumn = "SELECT LookUpColumnID, SOURCE_NAME FROM TB_LOOKUP_COLUMN";
DataSet dsColumn = databaseManager.GetData(sqlLookupColumn);
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboLookup = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
comboLookup.DataSource = dsColumn.Tables[0];
comboLookup.HeaderText = "Destination Column";
comboLookup.Name = "Destination";
comboLookup.DisplayMember = "SOURCE_NAME";
comboLookup.ValueMember = "LookUpColumnID";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(comboLookup);
comboLookup.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "Please Select";

//datatype
string sqlDataType = "SELECT DataTypeLookUpID, DATATYPE FROM TB_LOOKUP_DATATYPE";
DataSet dsDataType = databaseManager.GetData(sqlDataType);
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
combo.DataSource = dsDataType.Tables[0];
combo.HeaderText = "Type";
combo.Name = "Type";
combo.DisplayMember = "DATATYPE";
combo.ValueMember = "DataTypeLookUpID";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(combo);
combo.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "Please Select";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/how-to-set-selectedvalue-of-dropdownlist-in-a-gridview). You have to check `RowDataBound` from your GridView and assign a value there.

And here is the example:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType== DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
        DropDownList ddlCategories = e.Row.FindControl("DdlCategories") as DropDownList;
        if(ddlCategories != null)
        {
            //Get the data from DB and bind the dropdownlist
            ddlCategories.SelectedValue = drv["CategoryID"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry but this is in datagridview not gridview. Although there is no rowdatabound in datagridview but i will still look at similar events in datagridview. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, subscribe for [`DataGridView.DefaultValuesNeeded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.defaultvaluesneeded(v=vs.110).aspx) and set the default value for each `ComboBox` in a row.

```
dataGridView1.DefaultValuesNeeded  += dataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded;

private void dataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender,
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     e.Row.Cells["Destination Column"].Value = "any value"; any default value.
}
```